# Standard definition for $a$ being congurent to $b$ mod $n$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

My text puts the definition for
$$a\equiv b \bmod n$$
as
$$n\mid(a-b).$$
On the other hand, certain sources puts the definition as
$$n\mid(b-a).$$
Which exactly is the standard notation or is there a case of errors?

Comment: The two formulations are equivalent.  A number divides $a-b$ if and only if that number divides $b-a$.

Comment: That is true but given that for some constraint, say, a greater or equal to b for a and b are both elements in the set of integers, then it is obvious that leaves a negative quotient and using the other definition, it leaves a position quotient. Unless, of course, the signs of the quotients are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're equivalent definitions - that is,
$$n\mid (a-b)\iff n\mid (b-a).$$
If $(a-b)=nk$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $(b-a)=n(-k)$, and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you. I see why now. The equivalence relation stipulates only divisibility, thus the signs of the quotient is irrelevant.

Comment: @user If you're happy with the answer you should hit the check mark.  That's part of what motivates people to help.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Thanks for the head's up.